# how to deploy java desktop application as Java web start

Tags: java-web-start

How to deploy java application using java web start, any suggestion for pdf file which I can read and do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step tutorial here below, which shows how to create the .jnlp for a simple app, signing and packaging the `.jar`:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/

Comment: See also the [JNLP API demos.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).  Each has full source, JNLP and build file.  The file service demo. build file digitally signs the code, the rest are sand-boxed.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) tag itself is a convenient way to [learn more…](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)

Comment: Be sure to follow the small link (of the JWS tag) that reads 'info'.

Comment: IIUC, the link was once labeled `info` but now appears as [`learn more…`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info); see also [magic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69513/allow-specifying-sites-for-the-new-tag-formatting-at-least-to-some-degree/69644#69644) [links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000).